# Device API not returning recent data

Tags: api, openfda

Looks like the device end point for adverse events is not returning latest data or I'm missing something.

As on today (Sept 16th) when I trigger the below endpoint:
[https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:[20200801+TO+20200831]&limit=1000](https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=date_received:%5B20200801+TO+20200831%5D&limit=1000)

{
"error": {
"code": "NOT_FOUND",
"message": "No matches found!"
}
}

However when I try the same via the website, we can see 500 records.
Refer image below for the filters Used while doing the search.

[image]

Sample Result: https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfmaude/detail.cfm?mdrfoi__id=10475104&pc=QBJ

Can someone help me understand what is happening here pls ? Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> openFDA is experiencing some technical difficulties with updating the
> Device Event dataset, which is why it is slightly behind MAUDE. We
> will fix it shortly and report back once done.

UPDATE: The Device Event dataset in openFDA has been updated and this issue has been resolved.